# how to stop hash refreshing page in every browser

Tags: jquery, hash

I'm trying to add a hash value to my url using jquery, without reloading the page.

I'm currently using the code:

```
function showDesiredPage(desiredPage){
    $('.current-page').removeClass('current-page').addClass('previous-page');
    $('#'+desiredPage).addClass('current-page');
    location.hash = '#'+desiredPage;
};
```

however this reloads the page in every browser? it makes no difference whether I try to do:

```
location.hash = "#page2";
```

whats going on, how do I get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure about this? I've never seen it happen. In fact I just tested it on the stackoverflow.com page we are currently viewing, and setting `location.hash` to `#page2` or any value did not result in a page reload. There must be something else going on.